# Spin down hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I have a fairly old hard drive that I want to have spin down after say 30 or 60 minutes of inactivity. I flipped the web and found that I can set spin down time with `hdparm -S` and I tried that, setting it to 5 seconds - the lowest possible - but the drive does not appear to spin down. After issuing `hdparm -Y` it immediately spins down. I'm assuming that simply the drive does not support a "spin-down" feature, which seems kind of unlikely TBH - I can't see the model exactly but it's a 750GB WD from around 2007.

What I thought of was if I can get the time at which the disk was last accessed, I can run a cron and put it to sleep with `hdparm -Y`.

How can I get the last access time of a hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor i/o of a device with [iosnoop](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/iosnoop).
Monitoring sda for example:

```
# iosnoop -ts -d "8,0"                                                     
Tracing block I/O. Ctrl-C to end.
STARTs          ENDs            COMM         PID    TYPE DEV      BLOCK        BYTES     LATms
340208.638093   340208.654477   rsync        10244  RM   8,0      1814496      16384     16.38
340208.654523   340208.665321   <idle>       0      RM   8,0      1814464      16384     10.80
340208.725234   340208.749223   rsync        10245  RM   8,0      86260504     4096      23.99
340208.750150   340208.756908   rsync        10245  RM   8,0      86263552     4096       6.76
```